# XSLT, remove group of nodes if underlying node is empty and have specified attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove nodes if underlying nodes have empty values and have attribute as `ArrayOfValue`. I cannot write any code, only XSLT transformation are allowed in that moment.

So, for example I have this XML:

```
                <describedBy xmlns="http://example.ex">
                 <item>
                    <value xmlns:v1="http://example.ex" xsi:type="v1:ArrayOfValue" />
                    <characteristic>XXXX</characteristic>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <value xmlns:v1="http://example.ex" xsi:type="v1:ArrayOfValue" />
                    <characteristic>YYYY</characteristic>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <value>1234567890</value>
                    <characteristic>ZZZZ</characteristic>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <value>0987654321</value>
                    <characteristic>UUUU</characteristic>
                 </item>
              </describedBy>
```

And I want after transformation:

```
            <describedBy xmlns="http://example.ex">
                 <item>
                    <value>1234567890</value>
                    <characteristic>ZZZZ</characteristic>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <value>0987654321</value>
                    <characteristic>UUUU</characteristic>
                 </item>
              </describedBy>
```

Is it possible through XSLT transformation and how to achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start off by using the [XSLT identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own it will just copy across all nodes and attributes unchanged. This means you only need to write templates from the nodes you wish to change, or remove. So, in your case, it would be a template like this, to match the `Item` elements who have `value` of type "v1:ArrayOfValue"

```
<xsl:template match="v1:item[v1:value/@xsi:type='v1:ArrayOfValue']" />
```

Note the use of namespace prefixes, as the elements in your XML input are all part of a namespace, which needs to be declared in the XSLT too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:v1="http://example.ex" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="v1:item[v1:value/@xsi:type='v1:ArrayOfValue']" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your XML is not entirely valid, as it is missing the declaration for the `xsi` prefix, so I am assuming the root element actually looks more like this:

```
<describedBy xmlns="http://example.ex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```